# Dart with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, dart

Are there any recent working examples on using Dart with MongoDB. All of the samples I'm trying are getting errors. Example below.

Code:

```dart
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

main(){
  Db db = new Db("mongo-dart-blog"); // Throws an error.
}
```

Error:

```
Unhandled exception:
Invalid scheme in uri: mongo-dart-blog 
#0      Db.Db (package:mongo_dart/src/database/db.dart:25:7)
#1      main (file:///.../MongoDart/app.dart:4:11)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are running some old versions of mongo_dart samples.
I belive if you would get fresh version either from github https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart or from pub.dartlang.org samples and tests would run successfully.
Corresponding line in fresh version of blog sample looks like:

```dart
Db db = new Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongo_dart-blog");
```

And this is excerpt from comment for Db.open method

Db constructor expects [valid mongodb URI](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections).
For example next code points to local mongodb server on default mongodb port, database testdb

```dart
var db = new Db('mongodb://127.0.0.1/testdb');
```

And that code direct to MongoLab server *ds037637-a.mongolab.com* on 37637 port, database *blog*, username *dart*, password *test*

```dart
var db = new Db('mongodb://dart:test@ds037637-a.mongolab.com:37637/blog');
```

Unfortunately API DOC on github site is very stale, due to old dartdoc bug: 
http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5218

I hope it will be fixed soon and I'll be able to generate valid API doc for mongo_dart.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of trouble with MongoDB in client-side Dart myself. I ended up moving the Mongo calls to the back end, and using a combination of REST and Json to communicate between the two ends. You can find an example I wrote at https://github.com/RossBabcock3/dartgo3

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.